# Installing scripts on Heroku with setuptools

Tags: python, heroku, subprocess

I'm creating a python worker on Heroku that calls another program, [g2p-seq2seq](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq), as a subprocess.

That is, my main program calls

```
cmd = ['g2p-seq2seq', '--interactive', '--model', 'g2p/g2p-seq2seq-cmudict']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

From the [g2p-seq2seq readme](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq/blob/master/README.md):

> The package itself uses setuptools, so you can follow standard
>   installation process:
>
> ```
> sudo python setup.py install
> ```

which installs the script in `/usr/local/bin`

I was able to perform this on my local machine and successfully run g2p-seq2seq from my program. However, I am unclear how to reproduce this on heroku.

I attempted to add the following line to the Procfile (found from `pip freeze`),

```
g2p-seq2seq==5.0.0a0
```

but it was unrecognized.

Here is a link to [setup.py](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq/blob/master/setup.py)